Jhipster 8.7.0 - primeng : button style
I have generated a Jhipster application and installed primeng.
In vendor.scss :
@import 'primeng/resources/themes/nova/theme.css';
@import 'primeng/resources/primeng.min.css';
@import 'primeicons/primeicons.css';

In the component.html :
<button
  pButton
  pRipple
  label="Submit"
  class="p-button-success">
</button>

The button shows like that :

In Chrome :

I would expect it would be like that :

It's like it is not using primeng styles.
Any idea why?
In angular.json I have:
"styles": ["src/main/webapp/content/scss/vendor.scss", "src/main/webapp/content/scss/global.scss",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova/theme.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css"
            ],


Got the solution here solution
